# Is it possible to open up a tab from a lightning component? (not console)

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to do the below?  I need the button b/c I want to run some code to pre-populate some data under that tab.

[image: intro]

Comment: Are your tabs part of a custom component? Meaning, do you have control over the tab? If so, yes, it is possible

Comment: It seems to be the tab on lightning page as details is a tab for object record due to locker service dom manipulation is not possible if you are using lightning tabset then only it is possible

Comment: OK - thanks guys.  I may have to revisit this later and re-implement using tabsets